# How return 1 after insert and return 2 after update in a single stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

This procedure does not return 2, it always returns 1. How to return 1 when insert happens, and return 2 when an update happens?
It is perfectly insert and update but return value always 1.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  [dbo].[sp_SaveEmployeeDetails] 
     @employeeID int
    ,@first_name varchar(255)
    ,@middle_name varchar(255)
    ,@last_name varchar(255)
    ,@gender varchar(255)
    ,@date_of_birth date
    ,@EntryBy varchar(255)
  --,@ActionStatus int = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    DECLARE @ActionStatus int;

    IF NOT EXISTS(Select * From employees 
                  Where employeeID  =@employeeID)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[employees] ([first_name], [middle_name], [last_name], [gender], [date_of_birth], [EntryBy], [EntryDate]) 
        VALUES (@first_name, @middle_name, @last_name, @gender, @date_of_birth, @EntryBy, getdate()) 

        SET @ActionStatus = 1;
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
       UPDATE employees
       SET [first_name] = @first_name,
           [middle_name] = @middle_name,
           [last_name] = @last_name,
           [gender] = @gender,
           [date_of_birth] = @date_of_birth,
           [EntryBy] = @EntryBy,
           [EntryDate] = getdate()
       WHERE 
           employeeID = @employeeID

       SET @ActionStatus = 2;
   END

   RETURN @ActionStatus;
   --also try SELECT  @ActionStatus; 
END
```

Comment: When I wrote my answer, the question was a little different... How are you calling this? How are you retrieving the return value? Are you sure, that the `ELSE` part is reached? Is the employee updated in case it exists? And one hint. You might think about the `MERGE` statement.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: could you provide an example how you check procedure's result

Answer (score 1):

The value you return here

```
RETURN @ActionStatus;
```

...might be set to a variable directly, its the procedure's "own" return value. Look at this example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestReturn(@IntValue INT)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @IntValue=0
        RETURN 0;
    ELSE
        RETURN 1;
END
GO

DECLARE @RetVal INT;
EXEC @RetVal = dbo.TestReturn -1;
SELECT @RetVal;

EXEC @RetVal = dbo.TestReturn 0;
SELECT @RetVal;

EXEC @RetVal = dbo.TestReturn 1;
SELECT @RetVal;

GO

DROP PROCEDURE dbo.TestReturn;
```

It comes back with 1-0-1 as expected.

But this return value is bound to INT and is meant to reflect execution states (like error codes, success level...) In your case this seems to be the case...

If you think about output of any other data use OUTPUT parameters.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestReturn(@IntValue INT, @TestPrm VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @IntValue=0
    BEGIN
        SET @TestPrm='Value was 0'  
        RETURN 0;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @TestPrm='Value was something else';
        RETURN 1;
    END
END
GO

DECLARE @RetVal INT;
DECLARE @RetVarchar VARCHAR(100);

EXEC @RetVal = dbo.TestReturn -1,@RetVarchar OUTPUT;
SELECT @RetVal,@RetVarchar;

EXEC @RetVal = dbo.TestReturn 0,@RetVarchar OUTPUT;
SELECT @RetVal,@RetVarchar;

EXEC @RetVal = dbo.TestReturn 1,@RetVarchar OUTPUT;
SELECT @RetVal,@RetVarchar;

GO

DROP PROCEDURE dbo.TestReturn;
```

Comment: Insert and update operation successfully but always return  1

Comment: @OsmanGoni, just added examples to show the usage of return value and output parameters

Comment: i =sqlhelp.ExecuteNonQueryR("sp_SaveEmployeeDetails", htParams);Its sp calling problem using sql helper in .net

Comment: @OsmanGoni, Sorry, I did not see this comment, please excuse my late reply. As I do not know what your `sqlhelp` object is exactly, I can only guess: You are calling a Method with **NONQUERY**... This probably means, that this method will not return a resultset but only one scalar value - whatever this is.